# MigLayout unexpected layout with absolute cell coordinates and spanning

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I have a JPanel where I dynamically add and remove sub-panels of different sizes. Therefore I am using MigLayout with absolute cell coordinates. In the following case the result is not what I expected.

A simplified version of my code that illustrates the problem is the following:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutDemo
{
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int CELL_HEIGHT = 50;

    public static JPanel createBigPanel()
    {
        JPanel bigSubPanel = new JPanel();
        bigSubPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3 * CELL_WIDTH, 2 * CELL_HEIGHT));      
        bigSubPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));       
        bigSubPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        return bigSubPanel;
    }

    public static JPanel createSmallPanel()
    {
        JPanel smallSubPanel = new JPanel();
        smallSubPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2 * CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT));      
        smallSubPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));     
        smallSubPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        return smallSubPanel;
    }

    public static JPanel createCellPanel()
    {
        JPanel cellSubPanel = new JPanel();
        cellSubPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT));      
        cellSubPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        return cellSubPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() 
    {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MigLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // main panel where the sub-panels are placed in
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        MigLayout mg = new MigLayout("debug, gap 0 0");        
        mainPanel.setLayout(mg);

        mainPanel.add(createBigPanel(), "cell 0 0 3 2"); // [col row [span x [span y]]] 
        mainPanel.add(createBigPanel(), "cell 3 0 3 2");
        mainPanel.add(createSmallPanel(), "cell 6 0 2 1, align left top");
        mainPanel.add(createSmallPanel(), "cell 6 1 2 1, align left top");

        mainPanel.add(createSmallPanel(), "cell 0 2 2 1, align left top");
        mainPanel.add(createBigPanel(), "cell 2 2 3 2");       
        // problem occurs
        mainPanel.add(createBigPanel(), "cell 5 2 3 2");

//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 0 4 1 1");
//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 1 4 1 1");
//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 2 4 1 1");
//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 3 4 1 1");
//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 4 4 1 1");
//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 5 4 1 1");
//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 6 4 1 1");
//        mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 7 4 1 1");

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I remove the code line `mainPanel.add(createBigPanel(), "cell 5 2 3 2");` everything is as I expected it to be. But when I add the panel in column 5 and row 2, it looks like the panel is placed in an extra column between columns 5 and 6.

If I also add the code lines

```
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 0 4 1 1");
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 1 4 1 1");
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 2 4 1 1");
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 3 4 1 1");
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 4 4 1 1");
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 5 4 1 1");
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 6 4 1 1");
mainPanel.add(createCellPanel(), "cell 7 4 1 1");
```

the problem seems to be "fixed" and everything is placed in the correct column and row.

I suspect that my problem has to do with the spanning of the cells. 
Am I missing some MigLayout constraints or parameters? Or is it a bug in the MigLayout library?

I am currently using MigLayout V4.0 with java 7. I also tested my code with a V5.0 snapshot but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was the use of absolute positioning in MigLayout i.e. component constraints in the form `pos x y [x2] [y2]`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutDemo4 extends JFrame {

    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int CELL_HEIGHT = 50;

    public MigLayoutDemo4() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("gap 0 0"));


        pnl.add(createLabel("One"), "pos 0 0"); 
        pnl.add(createLabel("Two"), "pos "+(CELL_WIDTH * 3)+" "+(CELL_HEIGHT * 0));
        pnl.add(createLabel("Three"), "pos "+(CELL_WIDTH * 6)+" "+(CELL_HEIGHT * 0));
        pnl.add(createLabel("Four"), "pos "+(CELL_WIDTH * 6)+" "+(CELL_HEIGHT * 1));
        pnl.add(createLabel("Five"), "pos "+(CELL_WIDTH * 0)+" "+(CELL_HEIGHT * 2));
        pnl.add(createLabel("Six"),"pos "+(CELL_WIDTH * 2)+" "+(CELL_HEIGHT * 2));       
        pnl.add(createLabel("Seven"), "pos "+(CELL_WIDTH * 5)+" "+(CELL_HEIGHT * 2));

        add(pnl);
        pack();

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    private JLabel createLabel(String text) {

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);
        lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        return lbl;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutDemo3 ex = new MigLayoutDemo3();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example works as expected. It only looks like there is an additional column.
Panel 2 and panel 7 are left-aligned, so it looks like there is another column.
Putting `center` constraint to panel 2 and panel 2 will show that the panels
were just left-aligned and there is not additional column created.

So why it suddenly worked when you added those 8 small panels? The `MigLayout`
does not know exactly how much space it should occupy if asked to span say three
columns -- until the three columns exist. So by adding those small panels you
tell the manager what you expect from `spanx 2`, `spanx 3` constraints.
(In our case these are the third parameters of the `cell` constraint.)

Also note that it is preferable to use `w` and `h` constraints rather than
specifying size by `setPreferredSize()` method.

I have created a modified example, where I use labels instead of panels for
better visual understanding:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutDemo2 extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutDemo2() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("gap 0"));

        pnl.add(createLabel("One"), "cell 0 0 3 2, w 180, h 100"); 
        pnl.add(createLabel("Two"), "cell 3 0 3 2, w 180, h 100, center");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Three"), "cell 6 0 2 1, align left top, w 120, h 50");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Four"), "cell 6 1 2 1, align left top, w 120, h 50");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Five"), "cell 0 2 2 1, align left top, w 120, h 50");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Six"), "cell 2 2 3 2, w 180, h 100");       
        pnl.add(createLabel("Seven"), "cell 5 2 3 2, center, w 180, h 100");

//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 0 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");
//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 1 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");
//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 2 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");
//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 3 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");
//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 4 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");
//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 5 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");
//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 6 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");
//        pnl.add(createLabel("A"), "cell 7 4 1 1, w 60, h 50");        

        add(pnl);
        pack();

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    private JLabel createLabel(String text) {

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);
        lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        return lbl;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutDemo2 ex = new MigLayoutDemo2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });       
    }
}
```

In the following example, the labels 2 and 7 are centered. If 
left-aligned, it looks like label 7 sits in a separate column
but it is not.

[image: MigLayout 1]

By adding 8 small panels at the end, we tell the manager 
exactly how the layout should look like:

[image: MigLayout 2]

**Edit 1**

Solution as per comment. I took another approach. I achieved the requested
layout with splitting cells:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutDemo3 extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutDemo3() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("gap 0 0"));

        pnl.add(createLabel("One"), "gapright 0, w 180, h 100, split 2"); 
        pnl.add(createLabel("Two"), "w 180, h 100");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Three"), "split 2, flowy, w 120, h 50, gapbottom 0");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Four"), "w 120, h 50, wrap");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Five"), "top, gapright 0, split 3, span 3, w 120, h 50");
        pnl.add(createLabel("Six"), "gapright 0, w 180, h 100");       
        pnl.add(createLabel("Seven"), "w 180, h 100");

        add(pnl);
        pack();

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    private JLabel createLabel(String text) {

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);
        lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        return lbl;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutDemo3 ex = new MigLayoutDemo3();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });       
    }
}
```

There could be also other solutions.

[image: MigLayout 3]

Comment: What I don't understand is why the columns become larger than what is needed. Since Label 7 fits exactly the space in columns 6-8 (as they are before its addition). Could you maybe suggest a way to get the same result as in the last image only without adding the 8 small panels? I tried to define the size of each column, as column constraints but that results to a panel that is constantly 8 * 60 wide. What I need is a panel that has always the minimum needed size.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and tips. Your solution works correctly. Unfortunately it is not that flexible, considering that I want to add and remove dynamically sub-panels into my main panel.